# Does the rating of an AC fuse point to the amplitude or rms value of the current?

Tags: fuses

If one reads 16A on an household fuse. Does that mean that fuse can handle up to 16 ampere rms or 16A amplitude?

Comment: Since the fuse operates by heating, the answer should be clear.

Comment: Since the fuse's 'reaction' time is large compared to the mains frequency the individual current 'spikes' get averaged away before the fuse blows and RMS is what's left effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fuses melt due to \$I^2R\$ dissipation and, of course, this is power hence, the current MUST be RMS or DC (equivalent of RMS).

Comment: aleight but for an AC current, 16A rms current makes peak at sqrt(2)x16 ampere rigth?

Comment: imagine i pass a steady 15.999A rms AC current through the fuse. there will be instants when we freeze the time the current safely exceeds 16A. isnt that right?  some said no to my logic. so thats why u ask again here

Comment: The thermal lag of the fuse wire means that if you put a very fast temperature sensor (with zero thermal mass) on the fuse wire you would see a small ripple temperature of a few degrees. Bear also in mind that fuses take infinity to die at their rated current and maybe will break within 50 ms at ten times rated current. It's quite a science.

Comment: But imagine u apply sinusoidal Imax 18A(not Irms) 50Hz mains current to a 16A rated fuse for 24 hours. To me fuse will not blow because the rms of 18A is less than 16. am i right? im asking just to be sure

Comment: You are right (assuming a sinewave).

Answer (score 1):

Fuse rating is the carrying capacity (under some specified conditions) in RMS current.

Comment: so the 16A AC fuse will actually activate when the instantaneous current is: sqrt(2)*16 ..is that right?

Comment: @user16307: No, it will trigger under the conditions given in the datasheet, usually 16A continous is fine, a bit over it triggers after minutes or hours, more over in minutes, seconds etc.

Comment: As PlasaHH says, the current at which it opens will usually be much higher RMS current, unless the time is long and/or it's very hot. And yes, for a sine wave the peak current will be >22A. If it's a gnarlier waveform the peak current can be even higher so long as it is at high enough frequency that the fuse element averages out the heating effect. For example, a 1ms spike of 50A occurring at 100Hz is less than 16A RMS.

Answer (score 1):

These ratings show RMS current.