# How should fuse selection be made in discrete-time alternating current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal, fuses, circuit-protection, math

My V(t) signal progresses for hours as 0.75 seconds on,5 seconds off.(Let assume V(t)=I_lamp(t),R_lamp=1 ohm)

The general formula for fuse selection at room temperature is:
[image]

In summary,what should I write instead of "Normal Operating Current" in formula for calculation?(rms value or avarage value or another think)What is the my "Normal Operating Current"?
[image]

Comment: Why are you fitting a fuse; what does it protect?

Comment: I'd say \$\frac{\text{Normal (ON) Operating Current}}{0.75}\$ since the fuse must support the typical operating current while on, with a margin. But this can be complicated if the load is reactive (not just a purely-resistive lamp.)

Comment: The fuse protects the wire, not the load.

Comment: The main problem here is not the function of the fuse. I'm looking for how to find the operational operating current.

Answer (score 0):

I think choosing the fuse, you should account current which flows during your  0.75 seconds ON period. Effectively assuming your sine wave is there all the time. So, I think `Normal Operating Current = Vrms/R`. Again during this 0.75 seconds.

RMS or Peak to Peak voltage was discussed thoroughly here: [Does the rating of an AC fuse point to the amplitude or rms value of the current?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/228159/does-the-rating-of-an-ac-fuse-point-to-the-amplitude-or-rms-value-of-the-current)

Answer (score 0):

The fuse protects the wiring, not the load.  A pulsed or intermittent load doesn't matter very much. Perhaps you could use a smaller rating (the RMS of a pulsed waveform, by the way, goes as sqrt(D) times the RMS during the burst, where D is the duty cycle: here, D = 0.75/5.75), but such a fuse would also be more likely to fail under normal operation (thermal cycling stress?).

So, rate it for Vin(rms) / R(load), plus a bit.

Also, what the heck is this waveform, it's 4Hz?  This is clearly not mains voltage, or if it's supposed to be, it's not drawn to scale.  Is this a hypothetical question?  School assignment?  Surely it's not a practical situation; there are several real issues with a 4Hz powered lamp.

Comment: Yes,this waveform 4 Hz but 0.75 seconds on,5 seconds off.Should I consider the normal operating current as (17*sqrt2)/R? or ((17*sqrt2)/R )*0.75 or another thing.I am not sure.

Comment: @mike_lay944 17/sqrt(2) is Vrms here.